# How do I translate ODE23 from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, ode

I am currently trying to translate my code from MATLAB to Python. The issue that I have is with translating an ODE to Python. I have read on the internet that I could use scipy.integrate.ode/scipy.integrate.odeint for this. Unfortunately, I cannot get it the way I would like to have it.

My MATLAB code is as follows:

```
function [W] = PSFFA_MM1 (arrivalRate, serviceRate)

tspan = 1:1:96;
ic = 0;
opts = odeset('RelTol',1e-2,'AbsTol',1e-4);

[t,x] = ode23(@(t,x) myode(t,x,arrivalRate, serviceRate), tspan,ic,opts);

    function dxdt = myode(t,x,lambda, MU)
    l = interp1(lambda, t);
    mu = interp1(MU, t);
    dxdt = -mu*(x/(x+1)) +l;
    end

W = x./arrivalRate;

end
```

My Python code is as follows:

```
def interpolation(rates, point):
    a = math.floor(point)
    b = math.ceil(point)
    c = point

    return rates(a) + (c-a) / (b-a) * (rates(b) - rates(a))

def myode(t,x,lamda, MU):
    l = interpolation(lamda, t)
    mu = interpolation(MU,t)
    dxdt = -mu * (x / (x+1)) + l
    return dxdt

def PSFFA_MM1(arrivalRate, serviceRate):
    timeSpan = np.linspace(1,1,96)
    c = 0

    x = scipy.integrate.odeint(myode(t,x,arrivalRate,serviceRate))
    x = odeint(myode, ic, timeSpan)

    W = x/arrivalRate

    return W here
```

One of the points I am struggling with is that in MATLAB there is no need to specify 'x' explicitly, while this has to be specified specifically in Python.

I know that there is not really a specific question, but I hope someone could help me further.

Comment: I guess I am not quite sure what you are looking for, if you are looking for a solver that is similar to Matlab's ode23 then odeint is not it. There is an ode package that gives you the same type of integrator as ode23 called odespy, but the odeint integrator uses a different method for integration.

Comment: Which `x` are you talking about? It looks like you are supplying `x` to the integrator the same way in both cases.